# Why does a learning exercise warn that git commit -am is insufficient to add my new .gitignore to the repository even though git clearly added it?

Tags: git, gitignore

I am studying git and have come to [this exercise](https://www.learnenough.com/git-tutorial#sec-exercises_ignoring_files):

> Commit the `.gitignore` file to your repository. Hint: Running `git commit -am` isn’t enough. Why not?

I have done `git commit -am` and that seems to be enough.

```
michael@michael:~/repos/website$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    breaching_whale.jpg

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .gitignore

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
michael@michael:~/repos/website$ git add .
michael@michael:~/repos/website$ ls
images  index.html  README.md
michael@michael:~/repos/website$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   .gitignore
    deleted:    breaching_whale.jpg

michael@michael:~/repos/website$ git commit -am "Add gitignore"
[master e7cc08c] Add gitignore
 2 files changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
 delete mode 100644 breaching_whale.jpg
michael@michael:~/repos/website$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Could you speculate on what I did incorrectly and help me understand what is meant in the tutorial and why `git commit -am` is not enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a case of you did something wrong. `git commit -am` adds all tracked files to the commit with the message given as a parameter to `m`. You had (probably automatically) executed `git add .` prior to this command which adds untracked files from the current directory down to the commit as well.

For clarity, a tracked file is a file which Git is already monitoring for changes whilst an untracked file is something Git can see exists but has no history of. Just running `git commit -a` on its own would not add new files to the repository but simply commit the changes to files Git already knows about.

Answer (score 1):

From the man page of git-commit:

> -a
>   --all
>
> Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files you have not told Git about are not affected.

So the command only records changes to already tracked files. 
What you did "correctly" (not "wrongly") is that you used `git add` to add the new file.